# TypeError is not a function when calling with brackets

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I'm wondering why adding the brackets to hero.getSecretIdentity() causes a TypeError, but if I reference it directly within my console.log it works without issue.

```
var hero = {
    _name: 'John Doe',
    getSecretIdentity: function (){
        return this._name;
    }
};

var stoleSecretIdentity = hero.getSecretIdentity.bind(hero);
var stoleSecretIdentity = hero.getSecretIdentity()

//TypeError: stoleSecretIdentity is not a function
console.log(stoleSecretIdentity());

//Works without issue
console.log(hero.getSecretIdentity());
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are calling the function here

```
var stoleSecretIdentity = hero.getSecretIdentity();  // braces call the function
```

so

```
var stoleSecrectIdentity
```

isn't a function, but is set to the functions return value.

If you would write it like this:

```
var stoleSecretIdentity = hero.getSecretIdentity; // << without braces
```

you could call it later like you did here

```
console.log(hero.getSecretIdentity());
```

Comment: Okay and I'm assuming the reason I would see undefined when calling var stoleSecretIdentity = hero.getSecretIdentity would be do to the fact the getSecretIdentity is being invoked into the global context where _name doesn't exist which would be the reason for using bind? Is there any reason you would want to use .bind(here) vs setting the return variable from hero.getSecretIdentity()?

Comment: Well, in above example I think I would set the return variable. With bind you can assign what `this` refers to, so both will work though IMO it's a bit of a overload to use it with above code